# How to capture time/date when message was send/button pressed [ Vanilla Javascript ]

Tags: javascript, button, clock

Im working on a messaging app and i cant figure out how to capture time when SEND/Enter button was clicked and display it next to the message

Vanilla JS

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So are you trying to display the time the button was clicked, and display it to the sender / recipient in their local time?

If so, you should just be able to use the Date constructor like so:

```
const date = new Date();
```

That will give you the UTC time. To convert to local time, you can use the `.toLocaleTimeString()` method. This would log your local time in US format:

```
const date = new Date();
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US'));
```

So what you could do is have an event listener on the button, and when the button is clicked, create a new date, and convert to local time.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const par = document.querySelector('p')

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const date = new Date();
  const local = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US');
  par.innerHTML = local
})
```

```html
<button>
Click me
</button>

<p>
</p>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f198wvdt/2/

Is this along the lines of what you're looking for?

Comment: Worked like a charm, but now i have a 2nd issue, how do i display just time Hours:mins:Sec

Comment: Do you mean literally just take the AM/PM off the end? There's probably a way to use a date formatting method, but the laziest/easiest way would be (if we're going off the above code) to just do this: `local.slice(0, -3)`. That will give you the time without the AM/PM.